# Shortcode syntax errors

Tags: shortcode

Trying to write a shortcode to create a gallery but I am getting a parse error. My `foreach` loop needs correction as well as returning the correct output. Any help please?

```
function allphotos_shortcode(){

  $images = get_field('fl_gallery');

  if( $images ) {
      $output .= '<ul>';
      foreach( $images as $image ) :
              '<li><a href="' . echo $image['url'] .'"><img src="' . echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail'] . '" alt="' . echo $image['alt'] . '" /></a><p>' . echo $image['caption'] . '</p></li>'
         endforeach;
      $output .= '</ul>'
}

return $output
 }

add_shortcode('allphotos', 'allphotos_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing semicolons after `</li>`, `</ul>`, and `$output`. You also shouldn't be `echo`ing inside string concatenation and not adding the `<li>` tag to `$output`. The below is your code with these fixes.

```
function allphotos_shortcode(){

  $images = get_field('fl_gallery');

  if( $images ) {
      $output .= '<ul>';
      foreach( $images as $image ) :
              $output .= '<li><a href="' . $image['url'] .'"><img src="' . $image['sizes']['thumbnail'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" /></a><p>' . $image['caption'] . '</p></li>';
         endforeach;
      $output .= '</ul>';
}

return $output;
 }

add_shortcode('allphotos', 'allphotos_shortcode');
```

Comment: thanks Jacob, if I also remove the first echo in $image[url] it works as expected!

Comment: No worries. I updated my answer to remove the echo I missed.